# Phonegap SQL throws error but succeeds anyway

Tags: android, cordova

I'm currently using Phonegap 2.0 and running a sql transaction on my app. When the app starts,  I have the following code (edited to protect the hinds of certain programmers)

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var db;
function onDeviceReady() {
   db = window.openDatabase('gophersspots','1.0','Gophers Spots',200000);
   db.transaction(function(tx){
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS search_history (searchval_what VARCHAR (500), searchval_where VARCHAR (500), date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)');
   };
};
```

And in my pagebeforechange code for one of my pages, I have the following transaction:

```
db.transaction(function(tx){

tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM gophers_search_history ORDER BY date DESC', [], function(tx,results){
          //Do some code here....let's call is Success A.



},function(err){
        alert("Error processing get search SQL: "+err);
        console.log(err.code);
        console.log(err.message);
    },function(){
        //alert("Database SQL query successful!");
    })
```

Now here's the bizarre thing. When I run this query, the error message pops up. The code I'm getting is 0, and the message is 
    the statement callback raised an exception or statement error callback did not return false

But the success function runs too! Success function A runs, and it has results, and everything works just fine. Am I missing something?

Not sure if this is relevant, but I recently moved up from Phonegap/Cordova 1.7.0 to 2.0.0. I've yet to check the documentation to see if there was a change in syntax, which is going to be my next step. Just wanted to check if anyone here had the issue as well?

May the person who solves this for me mysteriously inherit a beer factory and a lifetime strip club membership. Amen.

Comment: Wrap the code in Try Catch and from the exception object, see the error string

Comment: @HamzaWaqas tried that, and it gave me some headway. Wrapping the entire SQL transaction in a try-catch doesn't work, but wrapping just the success function works. Thanks!

Comment: Pleasure. Always try to wrap your code to get the error string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it! Turns out it wasn't an issue with the SQL after all. Instead, the listview plugin was being called too early (this was part of Success function A, in the code above).

Comment: So was this an error on your part, or are you saying that there is a bug in the PhoneGap API?

Comment: @AshMenon can i know what you changed to work, because i am also having the same problem and struggling to fix it.

Comment: @user2143817 - it wasn't anything specific that causes this error, IIRC. You have to do it the old-fashioned way, i.e. commenting out line by line until you find the offending line. At least that's how I got through it.